# MongoDB: How to query a time-series with incomplete data?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm storing time series data in a mongoDB collection with one data point every 15min. But sometimes, due to bad conditions, some data points get lost. I have a dataset as follows:

```
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 12,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T17:48:09.000+00:00}
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 10,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:03:09.000+00:00}
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 14,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:18:09.000+00:00}
missing frame
missing frame
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 13,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:03:09.000+00:00}
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 15,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:18:09.000+00:00}
missing frame
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 10,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:48:09.000+00:00}
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 11,"timestamp": 2020-01-04T20:03:09.000+00:00}
...
```

I can't figure out how I can query this collection in order to have a continuous list of value every 15min in order to plot it and displaying lost messages (by changing the background color of the graph in case of lost messages). I would like to have a result aligned on every 15min (which would sum the values between t and t+15min) like this:

```
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T17:45:00.000+00:00, "temp": 12, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:00:00.000+00:00, "temp": 10, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:15:00.000+00:00, "temp": 14, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:30:00.000+00:00, "temp":  0, missing: true}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T18:45:00.000+00:00, "temp":  0, missing: true}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:00:00.000+00:00, "temp": 13, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:15:00.000+00:00, "temp": 15, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:30:00.000+00:00, "temp":  0, missing: true}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T19:45:00.000+00:00, "temp": 10, missing: false}
{"timestamp": 2020-01-04T20:00:00.000+00:00, "temp": 11, missing: false}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can do this with an aggregation query. The query can take an input of start and end timestamps, the time interval (i.e., 15 mins) and return the output as you have posted. The timestamp can be converted to milliseconds and for a given range of timestamps and interval arrive at the all the possible timestamps, and find the missing ones from the available data.

Comment: Thanks! yes I know that the approach is to make an aggregation query. But I can't figure out how to sum with conditions on the timestamp and to put a special value when no data has been found.

Comment: I posted the answer as I I had mentioned earlier. It gives the desired result. I might do some refinements to the query (and update the post later).

Answer (score 1):

Here is aggregation with the approach I had mentioned in my first comment:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $sort: { timestamp: 1 } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
           _id: null,
           docs: { $push: { timestamp: "$timestamp", device_id: "$device_id", temp: "$temp", missing: false } },
           device_id: { $first: "$device_id" },
           start: { $first: { $toInt: { $divide: [ { "$toLong": "$timestamp" }, 1000 ] } } }, 
           end: { $last: { $toInt: { $divide: [ { "$toLong": "$timestamp" }, 1000 ] } } }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: {
           docs: {
               $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ { $toInt: "$start" }, { $add: [ { $toInt: "$end" }, 900 ] }, 900 ] }, 
                    as: "ts",
                    in: {
                        ts_exists: { $arrayElemAt: [ 
                                              { $filter: { 
                                                      input: "$docs", as: "d", 
                                                      cond: { $eq: [ { $toInt: { $divide: [ { "$toLong": "$$d.timestamp" }, 1000 ] } },
                                                                      "$$ts"
                                                             ] }
                                               }}, 
                                     0 ] },
                         ts: "$$ts"
                    }
              }
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$docs" 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          docs: { 
              $ifNull: [ "$docs.ts_exists", { timestamp: { $toDate: { $multiply: [ "$docs.ts", 1000 ] } }, 
                                              temp: 0, device_id: "$device_id", missing: true 
                                             } 
                       ] 
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$docs" } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```

Using the following ***input documents***:

```
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 12,"timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-04T17:45:00.000+00:00") },
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 10,"timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-04T18:00:00.000+00:00") },
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 4,"timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-04T18:30:00.000+00:00") },
{"device_id": "ABC","temp": 23,"timestamp": ISODate("2020-01-04T18:45:00.000+00:00") }
```

The ***result***:

```
{
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-04T17:45:00Z"),
        "device_id" : "ABC",
        "temp" : 12,
        "missing" : false
}
{
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:00:00Z"),
        "device_id" : "ABC",
        "temp" : 10,
        "missing" : false
}
{
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:15:00Z"),
        "temp" : 0,
        "device_id" : "ABC",
        "missing" : true
}
{
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:30:00Z"),
        "device_id" : "ABC",
        "temp" : 4,
        "missing" : false
}
{
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-01-04T18:45:00Z"),
        "device_id" : "ABC",
        "temp" : 23,
        "missing" : false
}
```