# How to get records within time period of eachother with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to figure out how to get all records from a document that are close to each other in time. So if a record is within a set period of time from the last record include it. Basically I'm trying to create a bunch of runs from my data and if there is a gap in the timestamps I can assume that it is a new run. But since I don't know when the runs start and stop I can't use a fixed date.

I am using MongoDB with nodeJS.

pseudo code would look something like this:

if (previous record time is less then (current record time - 30)) {
 include current record in group
}
else {
 start new group of records
}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a post with similar question: [MongoDB: How to query a time-series with incomplete data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217428/mongodb-how-to-query-a-time-series-with-incomplete-data)

Comment: Thanks @prasad_, that is a good starting place and I'll try make it work. However, my goal is to group the sets together instead of a true/false type of thing. But that link will definitely give me something more to work with and hopefully it will all come together.